# Stuck on Would you like to integrate your new app with cordova to target

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a problem when I try to start a new project ionic apps :

**ionic start app blank** 
 **Would you like to integrate your new app with cordova to target ? YES**

and nothing happen, How I can solve this problem ? Help please

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you specify your ionic cli version? `ionic -v`

Comment: No In the last version the option --v is deleted instead you can use --type ionic1 options to use iconic1 without this option we are automaticaly use ionic 3 the update of ionic2 @SurajRao

Comment: ah.. I am not talking about the type during install... I was asking about the cli version. Try running the above command in cmd/terminal

Comment: @SurajRao Yes for my problem I found the solution just now, just create your project in the same DISK (C: D:) that you install in the node js and npm (cordova and ionic )

Comment: nice :) You can answer your own question and accept it...

Comment: @SurajRao Thanks for your help, I will share the solution

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem "Stuck on Would you like to integrate your new app with cordova to target" the solution is :

> JUST CREATE YOUR PROJECT FOLDER IN THE SAME DISK (Example C: D:) THAT
>   YOU INSTALL THE NODE JS AND NPM (CORDOVA, IONIC)

Hope this help you !

Comment: what is the solution for linux or mac OS?